# error while implementing mouse listener java

Tags: java, mouselistener, implements

I am currently not new to java but the first time I got this error here is a sample of my code ! Explains why even if I implements the mouseListener methods I cant seem to make my code work im working with IntelliJ

```
package com.company;

import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class AppMenu extends JMenuBar implements MouseListener {

    //  Constants
    private static String menufile = "File";
    private static String editmenu = "Edit";
    private static String aboutmenu = "About";

    //  Constructor
    public AppMenu() {
        super();

        this.add(newMenu(menufile));
        this.add(newMenu(editmenu));
        this.add(newMenu(aboutmenu));
    }

    //  This function create new menu for the App Menu
    private JMenu newMenu(String _name){
        JMenu newMenu = new JMenu(_name);
        //newMenu.addMouseListener(this);
        return newMenu;
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;
```

is the wrong import, you want

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

A quick look over the examples at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and the [JavaDocs for `MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) would have highlighted the particular issue